# Suffering indoor baby coffee plants

Tags: coffee

One year ago I received a little pot (well... it was actually a mug) of baby coffee plants, just germinated from seeds.

Of them, only three survived till today. I kept the pot indoor, in the same room I'm living.

During summer, the temperature reached 37°C, while now it's about 20-22°C.

The baby plants' leaves are yellowish, wrinkled and look a bit floppy.

[image: suffering baby coffee plants]

The last time I saw leaves in that condition, last summer, I watered the pot and many plants died, so now I'm not going to water the pot again.

I suspect that the temperature may be too high, but I'm confused, because last summer some plants survived while the temperature was much higher...

I cannot measure the humidity, but I think the atmosphere to be quite dry, because of the heating system.

What can be the cause of such suffering? How can I remedy?

Comment: It is not a water problem. To me seems more a fertilizer problem (probably too low, but it may be also to high, if you are fertilizing a lot: symptoms are often similar: one substance may inhibit an other one, and you see the lacking of such substance)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Well... it may be: I didn't fertilize them at all.

Comment: @Starnutoditopo Could you please tell us about the soil the plants are in now?

Comment: Temperature is usually not a problem unless drafty. Your winter range is quite temperate-mild-fine if stable. Though the 36C is shocking. Anyway, all plants drop older leaves with time, and potted plants are not nature's way.

Comment: @MackM it's "normal", "generic" soil for flowering plants ("terriccio universale per piante e fiori" in Italian, but my level of English is too low for me to be able to translate, sorry)

Answer (score 4):

The coffee plants do not seem to be suffering right now, they look normal for small plants, but they soon might be overpopulating the small pot. That pot is the right size for a single coffee plant about 10" tall.

Coffee grows on misty mountain slopes. Dry conditions will stress them.